# Executing multiple "code", arriving asynchronously, using vm.runInNewContext to run in a single process

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine

I observed the following when running vm.runInNewContext:

```
   vm = require('vm');
   fs = require('fs');

   function f() {for (l=0;l<1000;++l) {var ll=l*l*l; console.log(1);}};
   function g() { console.log(2)};
   vm.runInNewContext( 'for (i=0;i<1000;++i) { fs.writeFile("/tmp/1_", "111", f); }' ,
                 {fs:fs, f:f, console:{log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}}}, 
             {timeout:5000});

   vm.runInNewContext( 'for (j=0;j<1000;++j) { fs.writeFile("/tmp/1_", "222", g); }' ,
                 {fs:fs, g:g, console:{log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}}}, 
             {timeout:5000});
```

I would have expected the output to be interspersed with 1 and 2 but all the 1s are displayed first and then the 2s. In actual use, the code is sent asynchronously over the network to be executed in the vm and if one is in progress, it appears that the execution of the subsequent invocation will be delayed, even though the first code has async i/o calls. Is that correct? Any way to get around it. The code passed to vm will most likely use multiple promises with async i/o.

Answer (score 1):

this is related to nodejs eventloop. `for`/`while` loop in nodejs blocks eventloop thus any further code is not going to be executed till it ends.
I can't explain here more since its event loop is different topic from original question.

By wrapping `for` loop inside `async` you can avoid blocking event-loop.

Here is code that prints 1 & 2 interspersed as you expected and yes I had to ripoff some code to keep things simple.

```js
const vm  = require('vm')

const code1 = `
(async function(){
  for (i=0;i<5;++i) await Promise.resolve(console.log(1))
})()
`

const code2 = `
(async function(){
  for (i=0;i<5;++i) await Promise.resolve(console.log(2))
})()
`
vm.runInNewContext(code1, { console }, { timeout: 5000 })

vm.runInNewContext(code2, { console }, { timeout: 5000 })
```

output

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Comment: As I do not have control over the code that will be executed, is there some way I can wrap some code around the incoming code to get the same result? Any solution will be a GREAT help.

Comment: No, I tried many ways but couldn't .  BTW are you building arbitrary code execution engine ? because `vm` module is not made for that and even docs [warn](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm-executing-javascript) you about this. Consider doing something  [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD4KgwdjmdI)

Comment: Our vm executes node.js code using some of our library functions. Clearly there is a major security issue but since the scripts are written by internal developers, the sandbox provided by vm should suffice for now.  Earlier I had an implementation where the code was written to a file and executed as a separate process. I thought the fork was expensive. I should have done some more reading before asking my guys to implement using vm. In any event, we have multiple instances running and requests are round-robined so to some extent the lack of parallelism issue is taken care of.

Comment: piston that you referred looks good as a general solution for multiple languages but looks a bit heavy for what we are looking for, at least for now.  Is there another approach other than forking a new process or using vm to run node.js code in a script server?

Comment: We send code over websockets to the script engine, execute the code in vm and send the result back over websockets. Just to provide you additional details... we have configurable number of script engines running to overcome the issue I wrote about to begin with...

Comment: I would have also done same `fork`/`spawn` thing in this situation since it guarantees asynchronous-ness. But I am also confused why `vm` isn't creating new event-loop as it says in [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#scriptrunincontextcontextifiedobject-options) (see last words in this section) and you should be getting interspersed output without my patch.

Comment: I wonder if this bug has anything to do with it? [node bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3020)

Comment: most of are going beyond my knowledge so I can't say. I recommend opening  an issue/discussion  regarding briefing about "new event-loop " in vm docs and why its blocking main loop with minimal code for reproducing it. If you do, do let me know I am also interested in that.